# How can you tell if a method is being run in UpdatePanel postback?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

How can I tell if a method is running in the context of an AJAX postback (i.e as the result of a UpdatePanel (asynchronous) postback)?

According to [egoldin](http://msmvps.com/blogs/egoldin/archive/2008/05/21/how-to-tell-the-page-is-in-ajax-call.aspx) Page.IsAsync is a very common confusion that has absolutely nothing to do with AJAX.

The correct approach is to use ScriptManager.GetCurrent ( Page ).IsInAsyncPostBack.

Comment: Just had this problem, was using IsAsync instead of ScriptManager.GetCurrent ( Page ).IsInAsyncPostBack!!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use ScriptManager.GetCurrent ( Page ).IsInAsyncPostBack