# ASP.NET - How do I detect a partial postback?

Tags: asp.net

How do I detect whether a postback is a partial postback from any of my Update Panels?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265686/how-can-you-tell-if-a-method-is-being-run-in-updatepanel-postback

Comment: The IsInAsyncPostBack just return true, but if you have many updatepanels how do you know where come from ? so ignore the render on the rest ones. This answer worth a lot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am most likely wrong but I believe a partial postback is the same thing as a callback and there is a separate event for a callback.

Comment: Let say that you have 3 UpdatePanels, all of them have PageLoad. If one of the updatePanels make the click, then the program pass from all PageLoad, so to maximize speed, you need to know from witch UpdatePanel the trigger come from, and left only this PageLoad to run !, The rest must be ignore -  or else you loose in speed.